# Mongo: updating document and adding/updating lastModified

Tags: mongodb

I need to update a document matching item.id

Fields to update the document are stored in the object item

Query:

```
bulk.find({ id: item.id }).upsert().updateOne({ $set: item, $currentDate : {lastModified: true} })
```

{$set: item} - does the job and adds all fields from the item to the document, however when I add $currentDate field, mongo returns:

```
 errmsg: "Updating the path 'lastModified' would create a conflict at 'lastModified'",
```

Should I just do item.lastModified = (new Date()).getTime(), or I can do it via query?

Answer (score 0):

it's a Mongo feature-bug. In a single operation you can't alter single filed more than once. $set - sets the variable lastModified and then $currentDate tries to modify it right away.  Solution is to add lastModified to the object item

```
item.lastModified = new Date()
bulk.find({ id: item.id }).upsert().updateOne({ $set: item })
```